# Multiple executables in Xcode4 for debugging plugins?

Tags: xcode, audiounit, vst

In Xcode 3.26 I am used to having a variety of plugin hosts supporting various audio plugin formats (VST, Audiounit, VST3 etc) in the "Active Executable" menu. This is very useful for quickly debugging in different hosts. When I bring my projects into Xcode4 I loose this menu and I can't think of a way in which to get the same behaviour without making a new scheme for each format in each host. Anyone got any ideas if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to get used to the one scheme per host, sorry. Xcode isn't as ideal for developing desktop apps as it used to be.

However, [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) does have run configurations which are similar to Xcode 3's active executables. It's also a generally awesome IDE, so maybe it's worth trying out. :)